# Ring-Buffer Handler for individual types

Tags: c, pointers, buffer

I'd like to build a ring buffer API but instead of creating the buffer dynamically using malloc() in the API itself I want to pass the already existing array of variable types (uint8_t, uint16_t, etc.).

So I thought best way to achieve this would be to declare a struct holding all the required information and the required API functions

```
typedef struct ring_buffer {
    void * buffer;
    uint8_t element_size;
    size_t head;
    size_t tail;
    size_t max;
    bool full;
} ring_buffer_t;

ring_buffer_t buf_init(void * buffer, uint8_t element_size, size_t max);
void buf_add(ring_buffer_t * handle, uint8_t element);
bool buf_is_emtpy(ring_buffer_t * handle);
void* buf_pop(ring_buffer_t * handle);

ring_buffer_t buf_init(void * buffer, uint8_t element_size, size_t max){
    return (ring_buffer_t){.buffer = buffer, .element_size = 2, .head=0, .tail=0, .max=64, .full=false};
}

void buf_add(ring_buffer_t * handle, const uint8_t element){
    if(handle->head == handle->max){
        handle->head = 0;
    } 
    printf("adding %d at position %d\n", element, (uint8_t)handle->head);
    handle->buffer[handle->head] = element;
    handle->head += handle->element_size;
}

void* buf_pop(ring_buffer_t * handle){
    void* ret;
    if(handle->tail < handle->head-1){
        printf("Tail is at position %d\n", (uint8_t)handle->tail);
        ret = &handle->buffer[handle->tail];
        handle->tail += handle->element_size;
    } else {
        printf("Tail is at position %d\n", (uint8_t)handle->tail);
        ret = &handle->buffer[handle->tail];
    }
    return ret;
}

bool buf_is_emtpy(ring_buffer_t * handle){
    if(handle->head == handle->tail){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But that doesn't work as void* don't seem to be the right thing to handle this. How can I deal with pointers I do know the size at the time I create the struct? Because in the buf_add() I'd need to cast the `handle->buffer` to the correct pointer type in order to add `element`.

What would be the right approach for such a problem?

---

Based on the given answer I changed the line

`handle->buffer[handle->head] = element;`

to

`memcpy(&handle->buffer[handle->head], element, handle->element_size);`

What works so far but still gives me a warning that I'm `dereferencing 'void *' pointer` what is true of course but how would a correct dereferencing look like in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `memcpy()` and friends. Since you can't use a simple assignment when you can't provide a type you need to copy an untyped block of storage.

Please raise the warning level of your compile command as high as possible. Your provided source has some quirks. ;-)

**EDIT 1**

Quirks found:

Warnings reported by GCC 8.1.0 (MinGW 64 bit) with `-Wall -Wextra` after adding

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

`buf_init` has unused parameters, `element_size` and `max`. The source uses constants.

And there are warnings about dereferencing `void*` pointers and assigning the element to be added. Of course, because the source was not meant to be correct.

I would also use `size_t` also as type of `element_size` because it represents a size.

With `-pedantic` GCC warns about pointer arithmetic. But we do this on purpose.

**EDIT 2**

The warning about dereferencing a `void*` pointer is correct, so replace each of

```
&handle->buffer[offset]
```

by this

```
handle->buffer + offset
```

You have to implement address calculation "by hand".

If you use an index instead of an offset you would have to add a multiplication by the element's size:

```
handle->buffer + index * handle->element_size
```

An additional issue: `memcpy()` expects a pointer as the second parameter... This is my proposal:

```
void buf_add(ring_buffer_t * handle, void *element) {
    if (handle->head == handle->max) {
        handle->head = 0;
    } 
    memcpy(handle->buffer + handle->head, element, handle->element_size);
    handle->head += handle->element_size;
}
```

Comment: Could you reveal these quirks? :) I'll see what I can do with memcpy, already thought about it but somehow felt there should be an easier way

Comment: Note that pointer arithmetric or dereference on `void*` is non-standard compiler extension. Workaround is to first cast pointer to `unsigned char *` (or `uint8_t *`).

Comment: @user694733 That's right. The change will be another increment towards a better source code.